# Importing XSD defined with just <schema>, not <xsd:schema"

Tags: xml, import, jaxb, xsd, schema

I am trying to import part of the GML geometry definition into a new schema file:

```
http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd
```

This is what my definition looks like:

```
<schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://my.namespace.com" 
        xmlns:my="http://my.namespace.com"
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd" />
```

When I run my xsd through the JAXB compiler, I get this error:

```
[WARNING] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/geometryBasic0d1d.xsd', because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 
3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The document is accessible and can be read, so it seems to be #3 is the problem. Looking at the referenced xsd file, it's root is not "<xsd:schema>" but rather just "<schema>". I've searched around but can not find anything this specific on how to import an XSD like this. But I can't imagine I'm the only one doing this, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your geometryBasic0d1d.xsd ...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I was able to access the imported XSD file through a browser on the same machine, which led me to believe that the JAXB compiler (XJC) could do the same. When I ran XJC with the "-nv -verbose" options, it reported that the connection was timing out, which made me realize XJC itself could not see the imported file. Turns out there was a proxy setting I was overlooking. Once I ran with the proxy server specified, the import was successful.